# Same Base Package in Multiple Linked GPRBuild Projects

Tags: ada, gnat, gprbuild

With [GPRBuild](https://docs.adacore.com/gprbuild-docs/html/gprbuild_ug.html), I have created a library project called `Lib`. All packages in `Lib` reside within the package `Base`, which I use as a base package: to have a base package `Base`. For instance, if I were to create package `Apple` in any library or application I make, it would be written out as `package Base.Apple`.

The problem with this, using GPRBuild. In order to put things under the `Base` package, it needs to exist. In the GPRBuild library project `Lib`, I therefore have a file `base.ads` denoting the existance of package `Base`. Then in the project where I'm using the library `Lib`, let's refer to it as `Proj`, I also put all my packages under the `Base` package (the packages inside `Proj`). In order to do so, we need to create a `base.ads` file for `Proj` too with the package definition for just that, `Base`.

Let's have a look at the `gpr` project file:

```
with "lib.gpr";

project Proj is
   -- ...
end Proj;
```

Through this arises the problem; we suddenly have two files, both called `base.ads`, both defining the `Base` package, one in each project: the library project `Lib`, and the project `Proj` using the library `Lib`. As we have two packages (and their files) named the same thing, we get this error, which at all is not surprising, at compile time:

> `unit "base" cannot belong to several projects`

The question is: is there a way to have the same base package in multiple projects? Projects that are then linked together through an import (`with`). If it should prove to be possible, how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put the `Base` package in a project of its own. The following is a minimal demo.

In `base/`,

```
project Base is
end Base;

package Base is
end Base;
```

In `lib/`,

```
with "../base/base.gpr";
project Lib is
end Lib;

package Base.Lib is
end Base.Lib;
```

In `proj/`,

```
with "../lib/lib.gpr";
project Proj is
end Proj;

with Base.Lib;
package Base.Proj is
end Base.Proj;
```

Then,

```
$ cd proj/
$ gprbuild
using project file proj.gpr
Compile
   [Ada]          base.ads
   [Ada]          base-lib.ads
   [Ada]          base-proj.ads
```